# Disable feature secure processing in XMLInputFactory

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I'm going to split an XML file into multiple XML files, So I need an xmlStreamReader. While using XmlStreamReader it throws Exception Limit Reached. The XML Security Manager set some limitation for reading files.

I already tried setting up property FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING false. But it is not recognized by XmlInputFactory

```
XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, false);
```

I expect the XML Streaming Parser with no limitation of reading huge files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, Use Saxparser which supports a handler to parse the XML data also FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING can be disabled in SaxParser.

```
class ParserHandler extends org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler{
    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    // your operation
    }

    //other methods 
}
ParserHandler handler = new ParserHandler();
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, false);
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
saxParser.parse(file, handler);
```